# IE11 won't download anything and other issues on Windows 8.1 Update

Tags: windows-8.1, download, administrator, internet-explorer-11

I have multiple systems running Windows 8.1 Update - all fully patched. All virus free and with no add-ons or toolbars installed.

On one system, IE11 won't download anything unless I "run as administrator" for IE11. There are other postings with a similar issue on the internet - but no resolution.

If I go to, for example, the MS download site and click on anything and try to download (for example) Test.exe - the file is renamed "test_exe" and it fails to download. Ditto any other site where I download from a link (including from my own server).

Indeed, SuperUser.Com doesn't work correctly - the login button having no effect other than to refresh the page - unless I "run as administrator" on IE11.

On my other machines it works fine.

There obviously is a difference between them, but I don't know what - I've just restored an image of a clean install and then re-patched it and the same issue arises.

Most IE settings are set via Group Policy.

I found this similar problem here http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/33509-trouble-downloading-using-internet-explorer-11-a.html

I have UAC turned off on my machines - but turning it on makes no difference either.

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: All machines are being logged in as normal local Users and domain Users?

Comment: Does it work if you perform a [clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135)? How about if you log In as a new user? When you restored the "clean image", did IE work as expected before you patched it again?

Comment: Yes - I'm using the same user login on the domain on all machines. This user is a local administrator as well.

Comment: Also - yes, the clean image did work fine - so the patches must have broken it - it started (to my knowledge) after 8.1 Update was applied, but can't be sure. I'll create a new user now and login and see if that does it.

Comment: Yes - a newly created local user worked just fine as did a not-used-before domain user. Which means it is something wrong with my profile. Hurrah :S Don't really wish to remove this profile and re-add because of all the applications installed and configuration settings.

Comment: Anything in the application event log?

Comment: Did you try clearing all temporary files? You might want to [reset Internet Explorer settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737/en-us) as well. Also, a similar question that might be of interest: [IE10 downloading files has .exe become _exe](http://superuser.com/questions/745382/)

Comment: Nope - nothing in the event files. I did manage to get it briefly to work by changing the location of the download folder - but then on reboot, same problem again. Yes, tried clearing out temp files - the "clean image" that I restore is the machine as it was configured on first install - an image is taken & as all data is on server can restore at any time.

Answer (score 1):

I have a work-around. Take IE11 out of protected mode and all is well again.

Not ideal as you are now in "non protected mode" - but given that I can re-image my machine in the space of 5 mins it isn't a massive concern to me.

No idea why this should be so though.