# IE10 downloading files has .exe become _exe

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have a Windows 7 SP1 x86 machine with IE10, fully patched, which has strange issues with downloads in internet explorer.  Specifically, any exe (as well as others) has the period/dot/full stop replaced with an underscore.  As such, a download for `foo.exe` becomes `foo_exe`.

Attempting to download the file will initially fail with "This file couldn't be downloaded" and any attempt to cancel, open or exit the download prompt is ignored.  Retrying the download will allow it to complete successfully.

Attempting to update to IE11 fails, with a log entry in `C:\windows\IE11_main.log` reporting that an attempt to download required files was unsuccessful.

Diagnostic steps:

- "Do not save encrypted files to disk" option is cleared (per [KB2549423](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/browsers/cannot-download-files-from-secure-websites), [applies to IE9, but has same symptoms](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/the-dot-in-download-filenames-always-gets-changed/57b6b7c4-75c3-4a7a-ad45-1debfbe5ebae))
- Checked operation under both Protected Mode for Internet Sites and with Protected Mode disabled
- [Reset all IE settings](https://web.archive.org/web/20150312125631/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/923737/en-us)
- [Checked HTTP headers, `Content-Length`](https://web.archive.org/web/20160206220432/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/07/16/content-length-and-transfer-encoding-validation-in-ie10-download-manager-couldnt-be-downloaded-retry-cancel.aspx) and `Content-Type` specifically
- Checked for addins, malware, etc... using Task Manager, MalwareBytes and [autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
- Checked for network proxies, installed firewalls / security suites
- Checked for adequate free disk space
- Ran IE with add-ins disabled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running a [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) trace of the file download starting showed that the `CreateFile` calls to write to the Temporary Internet Files directory were failing with the error code of `DELETE_PENDING`.  Process Monitor was filtered such that the Path contains the name of the file being downloaded.

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) showed [open handles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsvistanow/archive/2008/03/12/part-1-using-sysinternals-process-explorer-to-solve-issues-when-trying-to-clean-up-files-and-folders.aspx) to the Temporary Internet Files directory opened by `svchost` running the Roaming Profiles service.  Restarting the service released the handle, allowing IE to properly write the file.

No further issues with downloads were reported.

Comment: Is this an answer to your question?   It doesn't seem to address it.

Comment: It is the IE itself that changes the file name right? for security? because a downloaded exe is treated special till the user give it an ok?

Comment: @Paul, yes.  Though it seems unrelated, it was the cause of the issue.  I believe it is similar to the http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549423/en-us issue, but instead of HTTPS preventing the file from being saved, a sharing problem prevented it from being saved.

Comment: @Psycogeek, IE is what is saving the file with the wrong name, yes.  It appears to do it for any unsafe file (.exe, .msi, .vbs, et al.).  Unless the user explicitly renamed the file, it would remain named with an underscore in lieu of the `.`.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this exact same issue and I figured out what caused it, in my case at least.

I had ran the CryptoPrevent tool from Foolish IT and one of it's options is to add a Group Policy to **Block executables from running in Temporary Internet Files**.

Once I undid this policy change and rebooted, IE 11 stopped swapping out the application.exe for an application_exe.

I just wanted to add this post since it was a solution in my case.

Comment: You might consider taking the part about this being an old question.  Just say that "I had this issue ... I figured it out ... it was because ... the solution was ..." everything else is just noise.

Answer (score 2):

As Mitch answered,

It seems to be a bug (handle leak) of PcaSvc (Program Compatibility Assistant Service) which should be fixed with: [Error message when you try to download a file by using Internet Explorer in Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2885210/error-message-when-you-try-to-download-a-file-by-using-internet-explor).

The main reason of `foo.exe` becomes `foo_exe` is that `CreateFile` returns `DELETE_PENDING` for a delete pending folder stored in Content.IE5. For example `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\9I1B2791`.

`9I1B2791` is opened by `svchost.exe`. You can verify this by using Process Explorer  or [Handle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) Windows Sysinternals.

There are many `svchost.exe` processes launched. You can find `svchost.exe` hosting PcaSvc by running `tasklist /svc`.

Terminating the problematic `svchost.exe` releases leaked handles (and also the delete pending folder is removed then).

So after all you can download files correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For me, in Internet Explorer 11, things were solved by uninstalling a program called Anti Logger SDK from a company called Zemana, followed by rebooting my computer.

Answer (score 1):

We've found restoring defaults and resetting user settings in Internet Options Advanced Tab resolves this issue.  Have yet to find out what is causing the problem.